# how to fetch data from hibernate query using database field names

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

This is my code for retrieving values from database.
This code is working fine but I am retrieving values using row number.
But, I need to retrieve values using database field names.
My database field names are `country_code` and `country_desc`.

```
Session session = SessionFactory.getCurrentSession();  
    SQLQuery sqlQuery = session.createSQLQuery("select * from country ");
    @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
    List<Country> ResponseList = (List<Country>) new ArrayList();
    Country response=null;
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<Object> objList = sqlQuery.list();
    for (int i = 0; i < objList.size(); i++) {
        Object[] row = (Object[]) objList.get(i);
        response=new Country();
        response.setCountryCode((Integer) row[0]);
        response.setCountryDesc((String) row[1]);
        ResponseList.add(response);
    }
```

Comment: 1] Why do you need SQL native query for it. 2] Why you can't fetch only required fields. 3] Why you haven't checked any documentation.

Comment: @NayanWadekar When I have a table with multiple fields ,it is easy to retrieve values using filed names rather than using row number .Suppose if I add an new column to the  table in between older columns,In that case fetching values by row id does not work .so I wanted to do using filed names.

Comment: You are shooting a fly with a cannon. Why don't you map teh Country to an entity and use an HQL query instead?